# Highstock scrollbar issue with single point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When only one point is plotted on graph than date range scroll is not working but still if i try to scroll at edge's its changing the position of point in Graph.

check fiddle here [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/pxCsX/24/)

Thanks

Comment: This one sounds like a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted same on highchart repository and they have taken this as bug.
and they will fix this in next maintenance release.
check here for reference - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5228

Answer (score 0):

Selected range using `rangeSelector.selected` is not avaliable in you chart because of data used. You could set `min` and `max` for xAxis to remove the issue.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pxCsX/25/